# Python call class method from iterable value in for loop

Tags: python

Say have a simple class as follows:

```
class Test:
    some_attributes

    def first_method():
        pass

    def second_method():
        pass
```

Now lets say I have put the list of methods in a list like so: `methods=['first_method', 'second_method']`

The question that has perplexed me is:‌ How can I‌ call the methods using the list above in a for loop. The scheme I want is like this:

```
for method in methods:
    Test.method
```

I have tried:

```
for method in methods:
    'Test.{}'.formats(method)
```

and

```
for method in methods:
    vars()['Test.{}'.formats(method)]
```

How can I achieve this concept?

Comment: Are `first_method` and `second_method` part of `Test`? Please show them as such in the question?

Comment: `first_method` and `second_method` are precisely the name of the methods defined on the Test classed.

Comment: Yes, but your question shows them as separate methods *outside* of the Test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getattr` Python method, to call methods by name:

```
class Test:

    def first_method(self):
        print("1")

    def second_method(self):
        print("2")


test = Test()

methods=['first_method', 'second_method']

for method in methods:
    getattr(test, method)()
```